Track the logs generated during the processing of a request in Spring boot
In my Spring application, I want to return the logs generated when processing the application as part of the response if a debug request param is set to true. How do I capture the logs specific to that request?
I have unique request IDs that are also being logged if that helps.

I think the whole idea is flawed and not how application logs should be used. Can't you create a common channel to output to and then include those "messages" in the response object - if you really want to return unstructured logs. Alternatively stream the app logs to some other place where you can query further and fetch them through a separate process in your app?

The reason I want to try this is when I run automated testing and identify cases where there are issues, I could also have the logs with it. I do stream the app logs to a separate place to query it further, but wanted to know if this is possible and if would make life easier

In Spring, with JUnit5, you can capture output with an Extension and examine it afterwards. Suppose you have a standard Spring component that produces log output:
package bin.scratchpad;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class OutputCapture {

    public void produceOutput() {
        log.info("this is the output to be captured.");
    }
}

I chose Slf4j, but it works with other loggers as well. Now you can capture the output in a test with the help of OutputCaptureExtension (see documentation here):
package bin.scratchpad;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.system.CapturedOutput;
import org.springframework.boot.test.system.OutputCaptureExtension;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
class OutputCaptureTest {

    @Autowired
    OutputCapture underTest;

    @Test
    void testOutputCapture(CapturedOutput output) {

        underTest.produceOutput();

        assertThat(output.getOut()).contains("this is the output to be captured.");
    }

}

This is an integration test, but it works as well in unit tests.
The output object provides access to the different output streams System.out and System.err (or a combination of both).
It is probably worth noting that this method tests the output, it does not test the data that is sent to the logger.
